# How to call/use r objects from a different session?

Tags: r, session, processing

I need to use an r object from another session but I don't know how to call it or load it.
Specifically I'm using R from within Processing(Java) and the session I stablished with the Rserve package to use R from within Processing is different than the one I'm using in Rstudio but I need to use an object (cv.glmnet object) that was created in Rstudio.
Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?
Thanks! every thought will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on the same machine, one (simple) way is to

```
 saveRDS(objA, "/tmp/objA.rds")    # adjust temp.dir as needed
```

and then do

```
 objA <- readRDS("/tmp/objA.rds")
```

in the receiving session.  There are better ways not involving files (eg writing to a Redis instance) but they require "more" from your side in terms of setup.

There is also a way to send an object via socket connections, but it is not trivial either.